# Как установить свой пакет с гитхаба?

Tags: python, git, cmd, package, пакет

Пытаюсь установить свой пакет с github в cmd. Пишу: `pip install -e git+https://github.com/ArturMistiuk/clean-folder.git` но выскакивает ошибка `ERROR: Could not detect requirement name for 'git+https://github.com/ArturMistiuk/clean_folder', please specify one with #egg=your_package_name`
В чем проблема и к какому файлу именно нужно указывать файл в github. Вы можете перейти по ссылке https://github.com/ArturMistiuk/clean_folder и посмотреть какие файлы у меня там лежат.

Comment: Я обычно формирую whl файл, создаю релиз, прикладываю whl к релизу, потом из релиза можно устанавливать командой вида `pip install https://github.com/юзер/репозиторий/releases/download/имя_релиза/имя_пакета.whl` (скопировать ссылку из assets релиза), или скачать whl файл, установить с помощью `pip install имя_пакета.whl`.

Comment: Файл .whl сам же создается после build в папке dist, верно?

Comment: Через команду `python setup.py bdist_wheel` должен создаться (пакет wheel должен быть установлен). См. https://realpython.com/python-wheels/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подставь имя пакета в конце ссылки `#egg=your_package_name`

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/ArturMistiuk/clean_folder.git#egg=clean_folder
```

Либо скачайте исходный код через `git clone` и запустите `python setup.py install`.
Если нет `setup.py`, введите python `-m pip install .` или `python -m pip install --user .`

Comment: Спасибо большое, так работает. Но можно ли обойтись как-нибудь без этого параметра? Я к тому что если пользователь качает пакет - он же не будет сам что-то прописывать там.

Comment: можно, главное чтобы в корневой папке вашего репозитория на GitHub был setup.py. подойдёт такая команда для установки pip install git+https://github.com/ArturMistiuk/clean_folder.git
В этом случае pip самостоятельно найдет информацию о пакете в файле setup.py. НО если у вас нет файла setup.py или информация в нем некорректна, установка может все равно не удаться.

Comment: Но у меня же вроде в корневой папке репозитория лежит.